# How crystal ensure stable frequency?

Tags: frequency, crystal

I know the crystal frequency (series also parallel) is given by its properties however I don’t understand how can crystals hold the stable frequency when power supply of oscillator changes.  Like LC tanks oscillators they also changes frequency a little when power supply isn’t stable.  Should they be driven with constant power to ensure constant frequency?

Comment: The answer to your question depends on the particular oscillator circuit. Therefore, you should give us some more information about your circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A crystal oscillator circuit **can** shift its oscillation frequency slightly with DC voltage changes. This is usually due to semiconductors changing their terminal capacitance when reverse biased at different supply voltages. The semiconductors will be in the amplifier and so, a variable supply will result in slightly variable oscillation frequencies.

> *Like LC tanks oscillators they also changes frequency a little when
> power supply isn’t stable.*

It's the same mechanism but, it's much more obvious when using a tank for setting the oscillation frequency. Typical is the single transistor frequency modulator: -

[image]

Image from [One Transistor FM Transmitter](http://electronics-diy.com/one-transistor-fm-transmitter.php). The base-collector region is normally reverse biased and, the microphone signal can change the reverse bias voltage and cause the collector-base to act like a variable capacitor. This in turn frequency modulates the carrier. But, the same effect can be got by altering the supply voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a crystal excited by variable power does change its resonant frequency. The equivalent resonant resistance also changes with drive level. From [Renesas application note 801](https://www.renesas.com/eu/en/document/apn/801-crystal-high-drive-level?language=en) . The parts-per-million frequency shift is generally smaller than the manufacturer's frequency tolerance - perhaps in the 50 ppm ballpark:

[image: image of freq vs. power level from Renesas AP801Renesas application note 801]

Microprocessor oscillators generally excite the crystal from an inverter-like amplifier. Voltage swing of the inverter output spans its Vdd-to-Vss DC supply voltage. At its extreme swings near Vdd and near Vss, inverter driving impedance drops far lower than the impedance near half-Vdd.
As you raise Vdd, not only does driving impedance decrease, but amplifier gain increases - driving the crystal with more power. A resistor in series with the amplifier output is sometimes used to soften these effects, and to limit crystal power.

Driving a crystal with too much loop gain also invites oscillation at spurious resonant frequencies that manufacturers generally do not specify. These can sometimes show up as temperature changes, or as drive level changes.